# How can I call Matlab functions using Erlang?

Tags: matlab, com, erlang, matlab-deployment

I would like to call some Matlab functions using Erlang.

I have two separate network models (one comms/control, one energy)

Ideally I would like an Erlang process to send a message which causes some Matlab code to run. After the Matlab code has finished it must notify Erlang.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

I am running Windows 7. Matlab appears to require use of Microsoft Component Object Models which do not seem to be commonly used with Erlang - hence my question...

Thanks,

Comment: This reference, http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/, describes how to call Matlab from Java.  Since Erlang/Java integration is more advanced than direct Matlab/Erlang integration, this might be of interest or use.

Comment: Matlab is NOT Windows only. I've been using it on Mac and Linux: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/sysreq/current_release/linux.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can run Matlab statements from the command line](http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/matlabwindows.html):

```
matlab -r "statements"
```

Erlang gives you the opportunity to [open ports](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) to execute OS commands. Combining the two features should do the job for you. Have a look to the [os:cmd/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1) function. For example, you could simply do:

```
os:cmd("matlab -r STATEMENT").
```